# nfcpy reading public information from contactless credit card with APDU commands

Tags: python, nfc, smartcard, apdu, emv

I am trying to read the public information from my own contactless credit card such as name, expiry date, pan number and card type using python and the nfcpy library, i am struggling to move beyond setting the PPSE and retrieving the card type eg) Visa Debit.

I have used the below code

```
import nfc
try:
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()
    assert clf.open('tty:USB0:pn532') is True

    tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda tag:False})
    
    cla = 0x00 #Class Byte - command class
    ins = 0xA4 #Instruction Byte - specific command for card to perform
    p1 = 0x04 #Parameters related to the command
    p2 = 0x00 #Parameters related to the command
    lc = 0x00 #If command has a data field, indicates the length of the data field
    data = bytearray.fromhex('325041592E5359532E4444463031') #Data field, if used data field needs to be followed by le field
    le = 0x00 #If command doesnt have data field, indicates expected length of response, 0x00 card gives as much data as is available

    resp = tag.send_apdu(cla,ins,p1,p2,data,check_status=False)
    print(resp)

    clf.close()
except Exception as EX:
    print(f'ERROR - {EX}')
    clf.close()
```

this code returns a bytearray with x90\x00 at the end to signify success and in the response it does show a "visa debit" card. But the response looks different from every other thread i have read, not all being bytes and actually displaying "Visa Debit" instead of the AID in bytes.

```
bytearray(b'o:\x84\x0e2PAY.SYS.DDF01\xa5(\xbf\x0c%a#O\x07\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x03\x10\x10P\nVisa Debit\x87\x01\x03\x9f\n\x08\x00\x01\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00')
```

I found the AID for Visa Debit card and tried sending the below APDU command,

```
00 B2 01 02 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 02
```

but only got response

```
bytearray(b'n\x00')
```

I am not sure how to move forward to select the individual records from the card, i dont know if nfcpy is the best library to use. Any advise would be appreciated.

*EDIT
To create the SFI file locator in python, i was able to apply bitwise operator directly to the byte without converting to binary string first.

```
sfi_rec_bytes = 10
p = sfi_rec_bytes[0] >> 3
i = p << 3
g = i | 4
sfi_recs = g
```

Comment: I setup an article series about getting data from EMV cards (e.g. Credit Cards). The code is in Java, but I'm for sure it will help you in your case: https://medium.com/@androidcrypto/talk-to-your-credit-card-part-1-select-ppse-paypass-payment-system-environment-674bbc9745eb

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thank you for the link i have read your article and been able to read the data such as PAN, expiry date from the card.  Although i am unable to retrieve the cardholders name.  Also on a newer contactless card after sending the initial request of 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00 and getting an AID in the response when i go to select that AID with the request 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00 i get no response and SW1 SW2 106 129, which i believe means a Counterfeit card? Can you help thanks?

Comment: For security reasons, the cardholders name is no longer stored on the card (since some years, don't know about the date, depending on CC company Visa/MasterCard/Amex). Regarding AID A000000003101000 - I cant see any CC registered with this AID, just a "A0000000031010" (missing 00 at the end) is a Visa card, so maybe it is just an extraction error ? Response "106 - 129" (in hex "6A 81") is a "Function not supported" response.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, maybe some of the guides i was following along with must of been older writeups back before they removed cardholder name then. I think maybe the last 00 was the LE or LC, i cant be sure now but ill test again when i next look at it, I suppose 6A 81 "Function not supported" would make sense if there was an extra 00 on the initial request.

Comment: Hello i am now able to read all the data from a card, but i am very stuck on trying to write the part to read/convert the SFI record part from the AFL data, with having to shift the decimal place 5 places and add 4, i am using python and have the AFL 10020500.  My code is sfi = 10. output = (sfi << 3) | 4.  But i am not getting the same result as i see in several articles i am following.  I am getting results 0x54 in hex and 84 without converting to hex. where as other online guides are getting a result 14.  Can you shed any light on this for me please?

Comment: Maybe these 2 websites may help you in calculating the SFI correctly: https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/readapplicationdata.html and https://salmg.net/2022/07/17/reading-emv-sfi-records/.

Comment: Thanks for the links, i managed to sort it out. I was trying to convert the first part of the AFL into binary and then apply bitwise operator to it, but in python you can apply the << operator directly to an integer. After that it worked fine.

Comment: If you solved your problem it could be good idea to "self answer" your question with your Python code, that can help future readers, thanks.